# Why use Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif as font-family instead of just sans-serif?

Tags: css, fonts

I can't see what is the point of doing this? For me it renders identically the same, so why should I use Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif vs just sans-serif?

Comment: Maybe for *you* it renders the same.

Comment: @greghewgill But shouldn't  Arial be user for windows users while Helvetica for Mac if I set just sans-serif?

Comment: @Core_dumped Most macs also have Arial, see [here](http://www.cssfontstack.com/), its a good resource font-family fallbacks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default font the user is seeing depends on the browser and its configuration. If you don't care what font the user is seeing—except that it is a sans-serif font, regardless of their system default—then by all means just use `font-family: sans-serif;`.

However, you can't depend on the defaults being specific fonts (e.g., Helvetica, Arial), as users can change them in their preferences. For a more uniform experience and design, it is a better practice to explicitly specify your font preferences, in order of priority.

In this case, it will default to using Arial, then fall back to Helvetica if Arial isn't installed, and then, finally, fall back to the system sans-serif default if Helvetica can't be found.

Comment: This is a more articulate explanation than the one I provided.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I stay brief when I can haha!

Comment: … uniformly speaking, Arial is **** though.
Maybe one day mankind will overcome Arial and the QWERTY keyboard layout. X )

Comment: also there're some considerations of different devices(maybe OS is more precise)... Arial and Helvetica respectively are the default installed sans-serif font on Windows and MacOS, then sans-serif can provide a fallback on other devices

Answer (score 0):

You should use "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif " because if 'Arial' isn't available the font will be changed to 'Helvetica' which is the same as 'Arial' and so on.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).